# html canvas not working after loading angularjs

Tags: angularjs, canvas

I'm learning AngularJS. I'm trying to add AngularJS to a long piece of code which works,and which includes some graphics using a canvas. I was able to reproduce the problem with the minimal code below. Basically, I just need to load AngularJS and that's it, my code doesn't work. I've been searching trough the angularjs site, but have not found anything.

If I comment the line that loads angularjs, a rectangle gets drawn. If I use the code as it is, the screen is empty.

```
`!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id='canvas' width='500' height='500'>Canvas is not supported by this browser.</canvas>
<script src="angular.js"> 
<script type="text/javascript" >

    function DrawMe() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        context.strokeStyle = '#808080';
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        DrawMe();
    });

</script>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Your code does not integrate with AnuglarJS at all?

Comment: it will, but at this point it doesnt. That's what is killing me, that i'm not even calling any AngularJS related stuff yet.

Comment: you are not closing the <script src="angular.js"> tag, add the </script> closing tag after it.

Comment: You are right. I'm so ...... if you write as answer I would mark it as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference to your canvas element:

```
function DrawMe() {

    // get a reference to the canvas element
    var canvas=getElementById("canvas");

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    context.strokeStyle = '#808080';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Comment: You are right. I added var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");  but still nothing. I'll modify the code in the question.